# Bootstrap Datepicker doesn't restrict value by min and max dates

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I need to limit the maximum date by today date, so I use the next code:

```
<div class="datepicker">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Birthdate, "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control", @style="max-width: 240px;" })
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        $('.datepicker input').datepicker({
            language: "ru",
            autoclose: true,
            format: "dd.mm.yyyy",
            todayHighlight: true,
            maxDate: new Date()
        });
    });

</script>
```

Due to some problems between different browsers I use a custom datevalidator also:

```
jQuery.validator.methods.date = function (value, element) {
    var pattern = new RegExp('^(?:(?:31(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]))\1|(?:(?:29|30)(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:29(\/|-|\.)0?2\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(\/|-|\.)(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$');
    return this.optional(element) || pattern.test(value);
}
```

As I wrote in the title a restriction by min and max dates doesn't work (I tried to set a min date too). I don't sure but maybe it is due to a cutom validation code. But how do I need to change it then?
**P.S.** Im sorry if my question is too easy but I don't know much JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using startDate and endDate you can set

```js
$(function () {
        $('.datepicker input').datepicker({
            language: "ru",
            autoclose: true,
            format: "dd.mm.yyyy",
            todayHighlight: true,
            startDate : new Date('2017-03-10'),
            endDate : new Date()
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="datepicker">
<input type='text' id='Birthdate'/>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You saved my hours. Did they change properties names?